# MongoDB Map-Reduce combine document with dynamic schema

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I'm trying what I think should be a simple map reduce, but am having trouble because I can't find a reference of how to write the server side javascript.

Given two documents:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("530c8b58d95cd926144055d9"),
  "atomic" : "p",
  "doc" : {
    "d1" : "t"
  },
  "array" : ["e"]
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("530c8b71d95cd926144055da"),
  "atomic" : "p",
  "doc" : {
    "d2" : "r"
  },
  "array" : ["f"]
}
```

I would like the result to be

```
{
  "_id" : "p",
  "value" : {
    "doc" : {  
         "d1" : "t",
         "d2" : "r"
     },
    "array" : ["e", "f"]
  }
}
```

The map function is:

```
function () {
    emit(
        this.atomic,                    
        {doc: this.doc, array: this.array}
    ); 
}
```

The *incorrect* reduce function is:

```
function (key, values) {
var reduced = {doc:{}, array:[]};
values.forEach(function(val){
    for(var i = 0; i < val.array.length; i++)
        reduced.array.push(val.array[i]);
    val.doc.forEach(function(kvp){reduced.doc.add(kvp.key, kvp.value);});
});
return reduced;
 }
```

The part with the array is fine, it is trying to combine the documents that is messing up (i.e. not executing due to missing function). I've tried all permutations I can think off -- if I add the val.doc to an array then they all show up, it's just that I can't figure out how to merge it into a single document.

The fields in the doc will be dynamic so there is no way to reference it by name.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure the reduced.doc.add bit will work.

Maybe try:

```
function (key, values) {
var reduced = {doc:{}, array:[]};
values.forEach(function(val){
    for(var i = 0; i < val.array.length; i++)
        reduced.array.push(val.array[i]);
    for (kvp in val.doc){
        reduced.doc[kvp]=val.doc[kvp];
    }
});
return reduced;
 }
```

Comment: Duh, the one thing I didn't try. Thanks!